# How do you convert Weight paint to new mesh layer in blender?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I used weight painting tool to select specific area of an dental model object and I want to convert that selection to new separate mesh layer, is there any way to do so in blender 2.8?

Please advise.
[image: Need to convert the area in red to new mesh]

[image: Need to convert the area in red to new mesh]

Comment: as Trey Harper says, there's a simpler way to separate or duplicate a part of your mesh, but if you really want to use the Weight Paint zone, you need to know that you've painted it has automatically created a vertex group in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, so you just need to go in Edit mode, select this group, press the Select button under the vertex groups list, it will select your group, then shift D to duplicate and P to separate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are after, but if you want to get a new, separate mesh of the teeth weight painted red, there's a simple way to do it.

In edit mode, you could Circle select (press C, mouse wheel changes brush size) and then "paint" the faces you want to select.

Then Shift-D to duplicate the selection.  Then, P will Separate the selection into a new object.

Hope that helps.